# How can I make each data in new row [data to csv]?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, import, row

Each data is in 1 row and 1 column. I want to separate them in csv file

```
from dataclasses import field, fields
import os
import csv
import collections
y=[]
Dict_New=[]
a=['Name','Count']
d={}
path = r"C:\Users\piotr\Desktop\CV"
files = os.listdir(path)
files_file = [f for f in files if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, f))]
print(files_file)   # ['file1', 'file2.txt', 'file3.jpg']
for x in files_file:
   y.append(x[:-4])
print(y)
Counter=collections.Counter(y)
print(Counter)
for key, values in Counter.items():
    Dict_New.append({'Name': key, "Count": values})
print(Dict_New)
with open ("test.csv",'w') as f:
    write = csv.DictWriter(f,fieldnames=a)
    write.writeheader()
    write.writerows(Dict_New)
```

I don't know why data are not separte in each row

Comment: Please post some sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

[`csv` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) stipulates you should provide `newline=''` when working with files, observe how opening is done in [`csv.DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) example

```
with open('names.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
```

this does apply also to `csv.writer` and `csv.reader` and allow code to work correctly indepedent from used ends of line.